# Scollview doesn't scroll a Linearlayout with layout_gravity="bottom"

Tags: android, scroll, scrollview, android-linearlayout, layout-gravity

I've got a Scrollview and a LinearLayout as its child. I set the Linearlayout's layout_gravity to "bottom", because I want to add some custom views programatically to the Linerarlayout, which are dragged down to the bottom by the layoutgravity "bottom".
I tried "top" as layout_gravity and the scrollview scrolls as it should,
but when I set it to "bottom" it doesn't scroll anymore.( The customviews have been inserted already and require more than the availible height )

Any suggestions?
Thanks in advance !

Here's my code:

```
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <!--Here are a few custom views added via code-->

            </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the fact that you have set `android:layout_height="match_parent"` in your LinearLayout is the problem. Try `wrap_content` and see if that helps.

Comment: Didn't help :( I've got an Edittext below this Scrollview. Might this have an influence on the scrollability of the scrollview?

Answer (score 0):

Add text view(Content which you want at bottom not to scroll) after close of scrollview and add property for Content which you want like:

```
        <LinearLayout>

            <!--Here are a few custom views Which you want to scroll added via code-->

        </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>                                                                
<!--Here are a few custom views Which you want to show at bottom without scrolling
    like <TextView> with gravity bottom attribute-->
</LinearLayout>
```